# No reason for downvotes for an accepted answer

Tags: discussion, down-votes, accepted-answer

Recently I have given an answer to a question and my answer was useful to the OP and he marked it as a correct answer and exactly what he needed, but then also I got four downvotes and that too without any reason. I mean, I can't understand why people don't give a reason for downvotes to the answer which is an accepted answer!!

Link to the question:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23486794/phonegap-navigation-bar-not-showing-up/23486968#23486968

And I even can't delete my answer because it's accepted by the OP.

UPDATE: Finally I have deleted my answer, because after posting a question here I got more and more downvotes :(

Comment: If you're interested in getting feedback on the answer, perhaps include a link here. However, that might mean additional downvotes if it's bad. Other than that, users will never be obliged to leave comments with their downvotes, and that it's accepted by the OP doesn't necessarily make it correct or useful.

Comment: I have given the link @Bart

Comment: That question looks familiar (well, I've edited it after all) but something about it came up. I can't recall what though. Let me see if I can find it. Not my downvote btw.

Comment: hehe yeah even I just noticed u have edited it @Bart

Comment: Basically the only thing you added are the script tags...it is a code only answer...

Comment: Ah, I knew that it had come up. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253690/ The basic issue seems to be that users thought the code you answered with was the same as already present in the question. If there is something in particular about the subtle differences that you think fixes the problem for the OP, perhaps point them out more clearly. Really state what the difference is and why that fixes the problem or why that caused the problem in the first place.

Comment: but I have made changes and I too provided working fiddle for that and it was useful for OP even he said in comment..now the thing is I even cant delete my answer because its accepted @Bart

Comment: So try to improve it @Neel. Make it better. Perhaps it will then attract upvotes. The subject matter is out of my comfort zone to give you any hints there, but perhaps others have a better idea what to address.

Comment: If you explain why the changes you made are needed, in other words, what is the root cause that your code works and that what the OP posted doesn't work, will make your answer better. And in the meta Bart linked post I think some assume you copied the jsfiddle from the comment under the question...

Comment: i havnt copied anybody's link i have gone through that fiddle and made appropriate changes and updated the fiddle i guess it should not be the reason of downvotes @rene

Comment: yes i will do it thanx @Bart

Comment: This is the problem with fiddles. All the meat of the question and the answer are somewhere else. It's not a good answer to say "I fixed the fiddle go look at it." Your answer should stand alone. Paste in the **relevant** changed lines and explain why your changes make it work.

Comment: [meta effect](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/204311/165773)

Answer (score 12):

An accepted answer means *this helped the person who asked the question.*

An upvote means *this is good and useful and helps **anyone who reads it.***

Your answer may have done the former, but clearly, many didn't think you managed to do the latter. They are not mutually inclusive, and downvotes *ought never* require explanation.